# Como pegar a descrição de um Enum no xhtml?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, demoiselle

Preciso de uma ajuda para resolver uma situação com uma classe Enum juntamente com o framework demoiselle. Ex.: eu tenho essa classe:
[image: Classe EnumTipoLei]

porem gostaria de que apareça em meu combobox o descritivo Ex.: Lei Ordinária, e não LEI_ORDINARIA. Veja a imagem abaixo: [image: tela do cadastro]

ok você deve ter pensado, ah faltou o adicionar a "descricao", mas foi feito isso também, ele não esta aceitando chamar o atributo descricao do método getDescricao conforme imagem [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uV8W8.png), veja a imagem abaixo: [image: input jsf]

Erro: [image: Erro]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta assim que vai dar certo:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="enumTipoLei" value="#{leiEditMB.bean.enumTipoLei}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{leiEditMB.enumTipoLei}" var="tipoLei" itemLabel="#{tipoLei.descricao}" itemValue="#{tipoLei}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

No ManagedBean:

```
private List<EnumTipoLei> enumTipoLei;

public LeiEditMB(){
    enumTipoLei = Arrays.asList(EnumTipoLei.values());
}

public List<EnumTipoLei> getEnumTipoLei() {
    return enumTipoLei;
}
```

Resumindo: criando um List do tipo do Enum apenas com o método get e no construtor do ManagedBean, colocando os valores String dentro dessa lista usando Arrays, funciona que é uma beleza!!

Boa sorte!

Comment: funcionou cassioliveira, valeu, muito obrigado!

Comment: Que bom que ajudou. Depois marque a resposta como correta pra ajudar quem for pesquisar sobre o mesmo problema.

Answer (score 2):

Para que seu item do `<p:selectOneMenu>` mostre a descrição nas opções você deve especificar qual propriedade deve ser mostrada através do atributo `itemLabel`.

O JSF padrão não tem o suporte necessário para o que você precisa com ENUMS. Logo, temos de recorrer a outras bilbiotecas de suporte. Nesse caso, a biblioteca [PrimeFaces Extensions](http://primefaces-extensions.github.io/) tem um suporte aprimorado de ENUMS para o JSF.

Usando o PrimeFaces Extensions seu código ficaria assim:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions"> <!-- Importação da biblioteca no XHTML -->

<pe:importEnum type="leiEditMB.enumTipoLei" var="enum" allSuffix="ALL_ENUM_VALUES" />

<p:selectOneMenu  value="#{leiEditMB.bean.enumTipoLei}">
    <f:selectItens value="#{enum.ALL_ENUM_VALUES}" var="e"
                  itemLabel="#{e.descricao}" itemValue="#{e}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Os valores do ENUM podem ser acessados através do nome da classe (configuração padrão) ou através de um nome personalizado (atributo `var`, no código acima `var="enum"`).
Também é possível obter todos os ENUMS da classe com o sufixo "ALL_VALUES" (padrão) ou um prefixo personalizado através do atributo `allSuffix` (no código acima usei `allSuffix="ALL_ENUM_VALUES"`).

Mais informações sobre o componente `<pe:importEnum>`: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/utils/importEnum.jsf

Comment: fiz como informou mas estou com problemas na importação ALL.ENUM_VALUES, segue imagem: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17997689/06%20-%20cabe%C3%A7alho.png, e https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17997689/05%20-%20erro%20importa%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20pe.png erro https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17997689/Captura%20de%20tela%202015-02-09%2008.33.35.png

Comment: Meu caro, me desculpe. Tem uma parte da resposta que está incorreta (no `<f:selectItems>`), onde escrevi `value="#{leiEditMD.enumTipoLei.ALL_ENUM_VALUES}"` deveria ser `value="#{enum.ALL_ENUM_VALUES}"`.

Comment: não deu certo, o campo selectOneMenu está trazendo vazio, segue imagem, https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17997689/07%20-%20selectOneMenu%20em%20branco.png

Comment: Como está o código do seu `<p:selectOneMenu>`?

Comment: <p:selectOneMenu id="enumTipoLei" effect="fade" value="#{leiEditMB.bean.enumTipoLei}">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{leiEditMB.enumTipoLei}"/>
                    </p:selectOneMenu>

Comment: Você tem que usar o atributo importado, nesse caso, o `var="#{enum}"`, então tente assim: `<p:selectOneMenu id="enumTipoLei" effect="fade" value="#{leiEditMB.bean.enumTipoLei}"> <f:selectItems value="#{enum.ALL_ENUM_VALUES}" var="e" itemLabel="#{e.descricao}" itemValue="#{e}"/> </p:selectOneMenu>` eu testei aqui assim funciona.